# hide show div using nav html5 query javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I've been reading lots of the other posts, and no doubt it's my inexperience with jQuery that is giving me trouble, but there are lots of things close to what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a div where I have a vertical navigation set of buttons.

Inside that I want the other divs (child divs) that will be shown or hidden based on the navigation button clicked by the user.

I want all of these divs to be in the same location on the screen...so, basically like a tabbed form but with vertical navigation.

I can't really figure out how best to implement the hiding and showing of each div when it's button is clicked vs. another div's button.

Here's the Navigation html I have

```
<div id="lowerDetail">
    <div id="lowersectionmenu">
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#Notes" title="Notes">Notes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#People" title="People">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="#NextTab" title="Next Tab">Next Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#LastTab" title="LastTab">Last Tab/a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="Notes">
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="noteEntry" id="noteEntry" class="noteEntryField" placeholder="Note Entry" size="100" />
        <button type="submit" class="noteEntryButton" id="sendNote" value="Submit" class="buttonAddNote">Submit Note</button>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="People">
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="addName" id="addName" placeholder="Name" size="35" />
        <input type="text" name="addPhone" id="addPhone" placeholde="XXX-XXX-XXXX" size="15" />

        </form>

    </div>

<div id="NextTab">Next Tab </div>
<div id="LastTab">Last Tab </div>

    </div>
```

This is pretty basic I know, but here's the CSS for that as well.

```
   #lowersectionmenu {
    float:left;
    width: 120px;
    border-style: solid solid none solid;
    border-color: #94AA74;
    border-size: 1px;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#lowersectionmenu li a {
    height: 32px;
    voice-family: "\"}\""; 
    voice-family: inherit;
    height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}   

#lowersectionmenu li a:link, #lowersectionmenu li a:visited {
    color: #5E7830;
    display: block;
    background: url(images/menu1.png);
    padding: 8px 0 0 10px;
}

#lowersectionmenu li a:hover {
    color: #26370A;
    background: url(images/menu1.png) 0 -32px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 10px;
}

#lowersectionmenu li a:active {
    color: #26370A;
    background: url(images/menu1.png) 0 -64px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 10px;
}
#lowersectionmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.noteEntryField {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    }

    .noteEntryButton {
        position:relative;
        top:20px;
        height:27px;
        outline:none;
        text-align:center;
        background: #66ff33;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#66cc33), to(#669933));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #66cc33,  #669933);
        font-size:14px;
        border-radius:4px;
        color:#606060;
        text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #f0f0f0;
        }
```

Now I just need some appropriate jQuery code to make the magic happen.

I appreciate any and all help.

I'm adding the jQuery given as an answer, but still no luck.  Maybe someone can tell me what's wrong.  All divs are visible, and the form fields are stacked...regardless of what I do.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#lowersectionmenu a').click(function() {

            /* hide any previous active nav and remove activeClass, fails quietly if none found*/    
            $('.navActive').hide().removeClass('navActive');

            /* create ID selector from this link */
            var id = $(this).attr('href') /* or using native script   this.href*/
            /* will return string "#Notes" which is exactly the same as ID selector string for jQuery*/

            /* show proper item and add active class used to find open element above*/
            $(id).show().addClass('navActive');

            return false; /* prevent browser default events for anchor tag */   

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: What is your main problem styling or which div should be hiden and shown ?

Comment: How to show the div or hide all other divs based on the navigation button clicked by the user.   The example from charlietfl should work, but I'm sure I'm missing something in the execution of it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work

```
$('#lowersectionmenu a').click(function() {

    /* hide any previous active nav and remove activeClass, fails quietly if none found*/    
    $('.navActive').hide().removeClass('navActive');

    /* create ID selector from this link */
    var id = $(this).attr('href') /* or using native script   this.href*/
    /* will return string "#Notes" which is exactly the same as ID selector string for jQuery*/

    /* show proper item and add active class used to find open element above*/
    $(id).show().addClass('navActive');

    return false; /* prevent browser default events for anchor tag */   

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LzmuB/1/

The toggling of an active class is a very common methodology so the currently active item can be quickly found and deactivated

Comment: Ok, I added this to my html5 document in a javascript section, but is there some specific jQuery version I need to refer to in the head of the html?  Right now, both divs show, and form fields are stacked on each other.  The clicking event of the nav buttons seems to do nothing.

Comment: make sure code is wrapped in `$(function() { });` so it doesn't fire before the elements exist. And make sure you include jQuery.js before any code that is dependent on it. Use a browser console to check for errors

Comment: I'm obviously still missing something...see the edit to the above code including the jQuery i've got...maybe you'll spot what's wrong.

Comment: code is not wrapped in `document.ready` handle as I posted in previous comment. This is the first step for any jQUery code http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Also learn to use a browser console to look for errors thrown and as a debugging tool

Comment: Charlie, you help has been invaluable.  I appreciate your patience as well.  I tweaked your code just a little on the Fiddle, and it now works as I was wanting...you have an end tag missing the <, and were missing a ; in one spot, but once I got those fixed, and added a couple more lines it all works great!  I tried to update the fiddle, so hopefully it's there if anyone else needs it.

Comment: the missing tag was copied directly from this page... I didn't feel like chasing it down